# It seems like I can't really get the output of my code to align properly using the format function. How am I supposed to do that?

Tags: python, format, alignment

I code that calculates the mean, standard deviation, modus, median, and quartile distance from a certain imported txt file with data.

However I've tried many things to properly sort and align the output to make it look somewhat neat, I figured the `format` function in Python would be my solution:

```
fmt = '{0:>18}: {1:>6.2f}'

for catlist in database:
    huidigeCat = categories[counter]
    fmt = '{0:>18}: {1:>6.2f}'
    #numeriek
    if isAlleenGetallen( catlist ):
        #continue data ( floats )
        if heeftFloat( catlist ):
            floatslijst = maakFloats( catlist )
            gemiddelde = getGemiddelde( floatslijst )
            standaarddeviatie = getStandaarddeviatie( floatslijst, 
gemiddelde )
            print( huidigeCat, fmt.format("gemiddelde",(gemiddelde) ))
            print(huidigeCat, fmt.format("standaarddeviatie", 
(standaarddeviatie)))
        #discrete data (integers)
        else:
            gesorteerdeLijst = sorted( maakIntegers( catlist ) )
            mediaan = getMediaan( gesorteerdeLijst )
            kwartielAfstand = getKwartielAfstand( gesorteerdeLijst )
            print(huidigeCat, fmt.format("mediaan", mediaan))
            print(huidigeCat, fmt.format("kwartielafstand", 
kwartielAfstand))
    #categoriaal
    else:
        #bereken de modus
        #print( huidigeCat,  "is Categoriaal")
        modus = getModus( catlist )
        print( huidigeCat, "Modus:", modus[0], "Aantal:", modus[1])
    counter += 1
```

And this is the output of my current code:

```
Category Modus: Music/Movie/Game Aantal: 209
currency Modus: US Aantal: 663
sellerRating            mediaan: 1853.00
sellerRating    kwartielafstand: 2762.00
Duration            mediaan:   7.00
Duration    kwartielafstand:   2.00
endDay Modus: Mon Aantal: 292
ClosePrice         gemiddelde:  38.85
ClosePrice  standaarddeviatie: 100.10
OpenPrice         gemiddelde:  14.21
OpenPrice  standaarddeviatie:  49.38
Competitive? Modus: Yes Aantal: 569
```

How do I make this output somewhat readable?

Comment: You are not formatting `huidigeCat`, causing the variation.

Comment: Side note: the [standard library `statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) can do all the work of calculating the values for you.

Comment: I've tried to change/incorporate huidigeCat in the formatting aswell, it didnt work, since some words are longer than others.  The point of the exersize was not  to import any of those modules.. but to do it all manually.

Comment: How am I supposed to properly format the `huidigeCat` to allign it properly, since the length of the categories of the output are inconsistent.

Comment: You already are formatting longer and shorter words, using a field width and the `>` alignment character. All you need is 3 such fields.